# Wrapping a Rubber Band around a Cube

Tags: recreational-mathematics, knot-theory

Imagine a cube wrapped with string so that each of the six sides has two linked "L's" on it, like this image (or some reflection or rotation thereof).

[image: one side of string wrapped cube]

You can get a lot of different knots and links depending on the particular choices made.

Are any of them the unknot or the unlink?

In other words, can any of them be achieved by wrapping real rubber bands around a real box?

Comment: Nice problem.  Can you show any work?

Comment: In theory there's only $2^6$ options to check. $2^5$, really, since they come in pairs (switching all crossings won't change the knottedness)

Comment: My suggestion would be to try the option that's the least alternating as possible - that is, every undercrossing that leaves a face is immediately followed by an undercrossing on the next face, and the same for the overcrossings.

Comment: _A_ rubber band, or possibly also rubber _bands_?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Not $4^6/2$? Each face can choose which pairs of threads connect and also the orientation of the crossing.

Comment: @aschepler Oh, you're right.

Comment: David - No real work to show. Just doodles and musings. I've pretty much determined that I have no better way to attack the problem than brute force. And I lack the programming skill to do that. I posted the problem in the hope somebody with the skill, tools and spare time would find it interesting...There are 4^6 possibilities (theoretically reducible by the symmetries of the of a cube) but even without reduction, that's only 4096 cases, which should be brute forceable at least at the level of checking an invariant or two.

Answer (score 1):

### No, it's not possible. The bands must be linked together before being wrapped around the cube.

Fun question. I wrote code to (intelligently) [manipulate and check the knotworks](https://pastebin.com/L3Fpcyya). None of them have the same invariant properties as an unlink—I checked the **crossing number**, the **number of three-colorings**, and the **Jones polynomial** evaluated at $t=9$.  This was sufficient to rule out all 216 distinct configurations (1024 nominal configurations before accounting for rotational and reflective symmetry).

1. The wrapped cube face shown in the question has 180 degree rotational symmetry. This means there are two options for each cube face—unrotated, or rotated 90 degrees—plus two more options if you're allowed to reflect it in a mirror.

   Out of $4096=4^6$ nominal configurations, I found that there are actually only **216** distinct configurations once you account for rotational and reflectional symmetry. (I am not sure why the number is $216=6^3$—maybe someone can point out a combinatorial connection.)
2. Next, I computed the *crossing numbers* invariant for each knot. The crossing number of two strings is the (signed) number of times they wrap around each other. The crossing number of any pair of strings in the unlink is zero; hence the only candidates for unlinks are those with all zero crossing numbers.

   However, out of these 216 candidates, all of the multistring knots failed the test. The only ones with zero crossing numbers were the single-string knots which, of course, have no crossing numbers at all because there are no other strings.  This made me suspect that none of these knots would end up being an unknot.

   There were 216 candidates, comprising 61 (one string), 90 (two strings), 54 (three strings), and 11 (four strings). Hence only **61 candidates** remained.
3. I calculated the *three-coloring invariant* next. This invariant says: suppose you color each segment of a knot in one of three colors, where the underthread at a crossing counts as two separate before-and-after segments. How many ways are there to do this such that (1) at least two colors are used in the coloring, (2) at every crossing where three segments meet (an over crossing and two under crossing segments), they are all the same color or all different colors.

   The unknot cannot be three-colored this way, due to a technicality that it can only be a single color throughout. Hence our candidates are required to have this same three-colorable defect as well.  Out of the 61 remaining single-threaded knots, only **thirty knots** qualify as being uncolorable.
4. Finally, I calculated the **Jones polynomial** for the remaining thirty knots.  Technically, I calculated the value of the polynomial at $t=9$ because it made the math nice and meant I didn't have to develop a data structure for polynomials.

   Programming the Jones polynomial calculation was admittedly a bit hairy—at first, I worried that I made a mistake somewhere, but I hand checked the answers for a few knots and tried it out on some well-known knots like the trifoil and it got the correct answers. So I have good reason to believe the code is correct.

   The value of the Jones polynomial for the unknot is a constant $V_\bigcirc(x)=1$. However, none of the thirty knots has that Jones polynomial value. Hence none of these single-string cube formations are the unknot, QED. (For good measure, I also computed the Jones polynomial of all 216 original configurations, and found that none of them matched the value of the Jones polynomial for any unlink with one, two, three, or four strings.)

I am sure there are deeper explanations for why this particular configuration cannot be made into an unlink, but for now I hope this empirical check will serve as a useful source of information and exploration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the geometric net of a cube:

[image]

I represented the cube as a graph $g$ of size $6$ vertices, each vertex of degree four (links to its neighbors).

[image]

Then I searched for an Eulerian path through the graph $g$ with the conditions that no three consecutive sides were collinear.  (That is, there must be an L turn at each vertex.)  Here is one such Eulerian path:

$\{a \to b \to f \to a \to d \to f \to e \to d \to c \to e \to b \to c \to a \}$

There are then $2^5$ distinguishable choices for "over-under."  Some will be trivial, others (ummm.... "knot"!).

Comment: What does "some will be trivial" mean?

Comment: The unknot.....

Comment: Why will some choices give the unknot?

Comment: You also need to consider the case of disjoint paths with together hit every face. If you have one band which goes (a-b-f-a-d-c-a) and one which goes (e-f-d-e-c-b-e) for example it may be possible they form an unlink.